# Put a layout on the right and left bottom in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layouts:

[image]

And it looks pretty much like this:

[image]

I want these two toggle buttons to be on the very left and right bottom like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to this. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

use relative as outer layout and put your linearlayout inside it.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout
     marginLeft
     marginRight
   />

   <ToggleButton>
      alignParentBottom="true"
      alignParentLeft ="true"
   </ToggleButton>

   <ToggleButton>
      alignParentBottom="true"
      alignParentRight="true"
   </ToggleButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice a RelativeLayout, where you put your two toggle buttons (with alignParentBottom, 
        alignParentLeft and alignParentRight), and then a GridLayout instead of multiple LinearLayouts for all your other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout with two LinearLayout inside.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        /*Top buttons*/
    </LinearLayout>
    /*Align bottom right with alignParent property*/
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        /*Toggle button right*/
    </LinearLayout>
    /*Align bottom leftwith alignParent property*/
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        /*Toggle button left*/
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below using `LinearLayout`....

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

OR, using `RelativeLayout` as below...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use RelativeLayouts. Learning to do what you want with LinearLayouts will make a big difference in the long run.

The solution is simple. Create a "wrapper" for your toggle buttons. (LinearLayout for each one), then use Weight to distribute the the layouts evenly from left to right.
Float the second toggle button to the right using the Gravity and you're golden:

To make sure that the toggle buttons float all the way to the bottom, enclose your grid of buttons inside a single LinearLayout and set the weight for that layout to 1. This will make your first layout will as much of the screen as possible. (Minus the size of the new LinearLayout you're about to make for your toggle buttons). This floats the code below to the bottom of the screen.

Here's some rough XML code for you:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let me know if you want the width of the buttons to fill the horizontal space fully or keep them small. The solution to making them fill the space is even easier than this. Best of luck!